# nginx won't start at boot using systemd

Tags: 15.10, nginx, systemd

I'm using nginx mainly as an http(s) proxy, for this I need to provision some domain names, which nginx tries to resolve (DNS) at startup.

If I start nginx manually (using systemctl start) after the pc has completely booted, this works just fine, however when just enabling it for autostart I get the following issue (mydomainname is something that normally would actually resolve, I just hid it here):

```
$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-02-13 10:41:47 CET; 45min ago
  Process: 844 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem nginx[844]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "mydomainname" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:8
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem nginx[844]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 13 10:41:47 mysystem systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am using ubuntu 15.10, I use the standard nginx package. What I already tried:

- Change After in systemd script from network.target to network-online.target
- Add nss-lookup.target to the After
- Put it to all three: network.target network-online.target nss-lookup.target

But it keeps giving that error.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging around I found out that the component enabling systemd to wait for the network manager to complete is not enabled by default. After enabling this as follows, it works perfectly:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```